# Python pydwf voltage input

Tags: python, input, pycharm, lib

0

I am using pydwf library to use it as a Wavegen. For example I want to give a Sine Wave to my microcontroller pin or just DC. I looked into pydwf examples and wrote some code but I cannot change the waves amplitude or offset or anything even though I use nodeAmplitudeSet() or nodeOffsetSet() functions.

So what am I missing guys anyone to help me?

Thanks in advance.

For Sine wave:

```
    #Before this line it takes the values (frequency,offset etc.)
    for channel_index in (CH1, CH2):
        print("\nChannel Info: CH",channel_index)
        analogOut.nodeFunctionSet(channel_index, DwfAnalogOutNode.Carrier, DwfAnalogOutFunction.Sine)
        print("Function info:", analogOut.nodeFunctionInfo(channel_index, DwfAnalogOutNode.Carrier))
        analogOut.nodeFrequencySet(channel_index, DwfAnalogOutNode.Carrier, frequency)
        print("Frequency info:", analogOut.frequencyInfo(channel_index))
        analogOut.amplitudeSet(channel_index, amplitude)
        print("Amplitude info:", analogOut.amplitudeInfo(channel_index))
        analogOut.offsetSet(channel_index, offset)
        print("Offset info:", analogOut.offsetInfo(channel_index))
        analogOut.idleSet(channel_index, DwfAnalogOutIdle.Initial)
        print("Idle info:", analogOut.idleInfo(channel_index))
        analogOut.nodeEnableSet(channel_index, DwfAnalogOutNode.Carrier, True)
        print("Node enable info:", analogOut.nodeInfo(channel_index))
    t_stopwatch = 0.0
    counter = 0

    while True:
        t = time.monotonic() - t0

        vx = 2.5 * math.cos(2 * math.pi * t * float(frequency))
        vy = 2.5 * math.sin(2 * math.pi * t * float(frequency))

        # To change the output signal on each of the two channels, we just need to change the channel's
        # amplitude setting.

        analogOut.nodeAmplitudeSet(CH1, DwfAnalogOutNode.Carrier, vx)
        analogOut.nodeAmplitudeSet(CH2, DwfAnalogOutNode.Carrier, vy)

        for channel_index in (CH1, CH2):
            counter += 1
            if counter == 1000:
                duration = (t - t_stopwatch)  # pylint: disable=superfluous-parens
                print("{:8.3f} loops/sec. Press Control-C to quit.".format(counter / duration))
                print("Giving output:", analogOut.amplitudeInfo(channel_index))
                counter = 0
                t_stopwatch = t
```

For DC:

```
    offset_DC = input("Please enter the DC Offset value:")  # V
    while True:
        try:
            offset_DC = float(offset_DC)
            break
        except ValueError:
            offset_DC = input("Please enter a valid number:")
    print("DC Offset:", offset_DC, "\n")

    for channel_index in (CH1, CH2):
        analogOut.nodeFunctionSet(channel_index, DwfAnalogOutNode.Carrier, DwfAnalogOutFunction.DC)
        analogOut.idleSet(channel_index, DwfAnalogOutIdle.Initial)
        analogOut.nodeEnableSet(channel_index, DwfAnalogOutNode.value, True)

    t_stopwatch = 0.0
    counter = 0

    while True:
        t = time.monotonic() - t0

        analogOut.nodeAmplitudeSet(CH1, DwfAnalogOutNode.value, offset)
        analogOut.nodeAmplitudeSet(CH2, DwfAnalogOutNode.value, offset)

        counter += 1
        if counter == 1000:
            duration = (t - t_stopwatch)  # pylint: disable=superfluous-parens
            print("{:8.3f} loops/sec. Press Control-C to quit.".format(counter / duration))
            counter = 0
            t_stopwatch = t
```